# How can I reuse this JQM function instead of copying it 5 times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I saw this [demo page](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.4/panel-swipe-open/#demo-page) and I build it in my page using JQM. However, to open the panel on swipe, the following function is needed:

```
$( document ).on( "pagecreate", "#demo-page", function() {
    $( document ).on( "swipeleft swiperight", "#demo-page", function( e ) {
        // We check if there is no open panel on the page because otherwise
        // a swipe to close the left panel would also open the right panel (and v.v.).
        // We do this by checking the data that the framework stores on the page element (panel: open).
        if ( $( ".ui-page-active" ).jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open" ) {
            if ( e.type === "swipeleft" ) {
                $( "#right-panel" ).panel( "open" );
            } else if ( e.type === "swiperight" ) {
                $( "#left-panel" ).panel( "open" );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

But I've got 4 other pages. How can I reuse the function for every page instead of copying it?

Comment: do you have the same panel on all pages? or are they different?

Comment: I have the same panel on every other page

Comment: then use _external panel_ and run the code one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using an *external panel* that can be accessed from any page. An *external panel* should be placed outside any *page*, i.e. should be a *sibling* of all pages, a child of *page container*.

```
<!-- external panel -->
<div data-role="panel" id="myPanel">
  <!-- content -->
</div>

<!-- pages -->
<div data-role="page" id="p1">
  <!-- content -->
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="p1">
  <!-- content -->
</div>
```

And then *initialize* it manually and *enhance* its' contents.

```
$(function () {
   $("#myPanel").panel().enhanceWithin();
});
```

To add *swipe* listener, run the code once `.one()` on `pagecreate`.

```
$(document).one("pagecreate", function () {
    $(document).on("swipeleft", function (e) {
        if ($(".ui-page-active").jqmData("panel") !== "open") {
            $("#myPanel").panel("open");
        }
    });
});
```

---

However, if you want to use a different panel for each page, then you need to run code whenever `pagecreate` triggers by utilizing `event.target`. Moreover, to target the panel in the page where *swipe* event was triggered, you need to use *activePage* method.

I forgot to mention that `pagecreate` event fires once per page, hence, the below code will be executed one time per page.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function (e) {
    $(e.target).on("swipeleft", function (e) {
        var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");
        if (activePage.jqmData("panel") !== "open") {
            $("[data-role=panel]", activePage).panel("open");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure here it has to be an "=="? var activePage **==** ...;

Comment: @minimen I've included a short explanation about `pagecreate` event.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's a anonimouse function, just give it a name, save it in a *.js file and include that file in your four pages. Here the fuction with a name:

```
function withName( e ) {
            // We check if there is no open panel on the page because otherwise
            // a swipe to close the left panel would also open the right panel (and v.v.).
            // We do this by checking the data that the framework stores on the page element (panel: open).
            if ( $( ".ui-page-active" ).jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open" ) {
                if ( e.type === "swipeleft" ) {
                    $( "#right-panel" ).panel( "open" );
                } else if ( e.type === "swiperight" ) {
                    $( "#left-panel" ).panel( "open" );
                }
            }
        }

function moreName() {
        $( document ).on( "swipeleft swiperight", "#demo-page", withName);
    }

$( document ).on( "pagecreate", "#demo-page", moreName);
```

Comment: this will run on `"#demo-page"` page only. if he has `#demo-page2`,  `#demo-page3`, `#demo-page4`, he will end up calling `moreName` on each `pagecreate` of the aforementioned pages.